# Textview onclick bg color change in android

Tags: android

If we click any of the Textview within a Listview, background color should have to change and onclick release, it should have to change to transparent color in android.Is there anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html !
There is very good explanation regarding concept you looking for.

Comment: If there is onitemclick listener then only this type of styles is working.Here onclicklistener for Textview is needed,so not able to apply these styles.If u provide code for this in OnClickListener of Textview then it will be useful.

Answer (score 14):

Create a **textview_selector.xml** in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_color"
          android:state_pressed="true" />    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_color" />
</selector>
```

Define colors in **color.xml** in res>values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

     <drawable name="pressed_color">#FF0000</drawable> <!--custom color for pressed state -->
    <drawable name="normal_color">#00FFFFFF</drawable> <!--transperent color for normal state -->
</resources>
```

Now,you need to use it where you define textviews as a part of your listitem.

```
<TextView 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/textview1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="This is sample!"
      android:background="@drawable/textview_selector"   
      android:clickable="true"   
/>
```

Comment: This way is Not working,if there is any OnClickListener for Textview.

Comment: I think,you might be getting problem as your clicks on listitem and textview conflicts.

Comment: yes,if there is no  OnClickListener for Textview and if there is onItemClickListener for Listview then it is working.But here,OnClickListener for Textview is needed for the functionalities.How achieve it dynamically in OnClickListener ?

Comment: try taking a button instead of textview and set its text and background color as per your requirement in your custom adapter class.

Comment: But unfortunately button is not in my requirement.Only textview is needed.

Comment: i understand but you will get problem in catching textview's onClick.so i suggested to use button if it doesn't make much difference in fuctionality. you can always change its background,text and feel as textview.